# How to hide preious value before append

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax to make notifications on my system but the problem is that every time the Ajax returns the value the value is keep adding to the notification bar how can i remove the previously appended value  before appending the new value

```
function loadLog(){
  $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
            url: "notify.php",
            cache: false,
        data :{ },
            success: function(data){
          //alert(data);
          //console.log('my message' + data);
          $('.ajax-load').hide();
          $("#notifications").append(data);
                 //console.log(html);
            },
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$("#notifications").empty()` to empty the element, before appending new elements to it.